# What could account for a very, very large change in pid's in a short amount of time?

Tags: process-management, out-of-memory

On an Ubuntu 20.x server, we are having some OOM Killer issues, where it kills a Java process.  We have been unable to find any memory leaks.

But this morning, we got a rare gift, which is two oom-kills in a short period of time.  The first occurred at 9:33:39, and the second was at 9:44:14.  Here are the CPU and Memory utilization during the time of these events.
[image]
[image]

What is truly bizarre, though, is that the pid of the first process was about 412,000 less than the second pid less than 11 minutes later.  They were 1328 and then 413972.

So we have begun to suspect something outside of the Java process.  We have four docker containers running the Java/Spring/RxJava highly multi-threaded application, as well as Postgres, Caddy, and Watchtower (Docker Hub watcher).

But the pids of the back-to-back oom-kills really seem like an important clue.

Is it even feasible to think that some rogue actor could spawn and terminate 412,644 processes over the course of 635 seconds?  That's 649.8 processes per second.  What in Linux could do that other than malware?  Could Caddy or Postgres possibly cause that to happen?  Wouldn't the CPU and memory reflect that kind of activity?  Could the threads used in Java cause this?  Even if there were a DDoS attack, could Caddy account for that many processes?  Is there any other possible explanation for pids to be so far apart in such a short amount of time?

Is there any logging on the machine that might be useful that we might have missed?

Comment: You can enable [auditing](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/auditd.8.html) and look for forks and possibly execs to see clearer.